# What tools exist for comparing C++ code to coding guidelines?

Tags: c++, coding-style

There exist tools for comparing code against a custom specified set of coding guidelines/standards for a variety of languages (rather than pure static analysis for common defects).  Examples include [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) for .Net code and [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) for Java, but I was wondering what examples people know of in the C++ world.

[An existing question was asked regarding free tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards) which provided examples like [Vera](http://www.inspirel.com/vera/) but I was also wondering about commercial tools that may be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full list that I managed to generate:

- [PRQA's QA C++](http://www.programmingresearch.com/QACPP_MAIN.html#1_1)
- [Parasoft's C++Test](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/home.jsp?product=CppTest&itemId=47)
- [MS Visual Studio Team System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181459(VS.80).aspx) seems to have some functionality but it's hard to tell via their website.
- [GrammaTech CodeSonar](http://www.grammatech.com/products/codesonar/overview.html)
- [Coverity Extend](http://www.coverity.com/products/static-analysis-extend.html)

The last two provide some functionality but not particularly customisable ones:

- [Klocwork Insight](http://www.klocwork.com/)
- [Rational PurifyPlus](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purifyplus/win/features/?S_CMP=wspace)

Answer (score 5):

A tool used by us was CodeWizard from Parasoft. But I think the new version is called "Parasoft C++ Test". From the homepage:

- Static analysis of code for
  compliance with user-selected coding
  standards
- Graphical RuleWizard
  editor for creating custom coding
  rules
- Static code path simulation
  for identifying potential runtime
  errors
- Automated code review with a
  graphical interface and progress
  tracking
- Automated generation and
  execution of unit and component-level
  tests
- Flexible stub framework
- Full support for regression testing
- Code coverage analysis with code
  highlighting
- Runtime memory error
  checking during unit test execution
- Full team deployment infrastructure
  for desktop and command line usage

Answer (score 4):

**DISCLAIMER: Working on this tool is my day job.**

I'm obviously biased, but one of the main features of QA C++ is Coding Standard enforcement.  For example we do JSF++ and MISRA C++ enforcement.  You can read more about this [here](http://www.programmingresearch.com/QACPP_MAIN.html#1_3).

Comment: This answer is relevant, and I believe plugging your IP is acceptable when this is relevant to the question.  See this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/741/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-promote-yourself-using-stackoverflow/756#756 some discussion on this point.

Answer (score 2):

`astyle` is a common Unix tool that reformats source to a specified style. It supports most C-like languages. I know of no similar commercial tools.

Comment: I think the question is more about idioms and variable names than indentation and newlines.

Answer (score 2):

> I was also wondering about commercial tools that may be available.

Visual Studio Team System Edition 2005/2008 does have some such stuff. They also have a facility to enforce a set of rules on a whole team. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether you looking for a tool with built-in rules or want to validate against your custom rules. If it is the second, you may find it useful to implement searches for undesirable patterns based on regexp. Depending on your needs, Metrix++ http://metrixplusplus.sourceforge.net/ may offer helpful framework.