# Are there any tools for verifying coding standards?

Tags: c++, coding-style, verification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)

I'm having some trouble finding a tool for verifying if a code respects certain coding rules.

For example I want to make sure of things like the following:

- class names start with a C
- class member names start with m_
- global variables should start with g_
- static variables should start with s_
- comments should follow the doxygen rules
- ...

Is there a tool that can be customized to meet this requirements? (It doesn't matter if it's open source/free or commercial, though free would be nice ... ).

Even if parts of the requirements can be achieved it would be good.

PS: The customizing part is very important as the product may be used for other projects also, projects where the coding standards can be different

Comment: [Duplicate 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards), [duplicate 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641050/what-tools-exist-for-comparing-c-code-to-coding-guidelines).

Comment: Verification takes place during code review. Why to use special tools for that purpose?