# Good coding guidelines tool for C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tools exist for comparing C++ code to coding guidelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641050/what-tools-exist-for-comparing-c-code-to-coding-guidelines)

Can any one suggest any good coding guidelines tool for C++ which must be configurable according to specific requirements?

Comment: Many dupes including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641050/what-tools-exist-for-comparing-c-code-to-coding-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

I've always found the [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) to be a good one.

Comment: OK for a better C but not if you use exceptions and RTTI - which is another argument

Comment: He is asking for a TOOL, not a document.