# StyleCop for C++

Tags: c++, coding-style

I would like to ask do You know any programs similar to [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) but for C++?

Comment: StyleCop presumable identifies and complains about code formatting and usage issues, no?

Comment: I edited you post to add a link to the tool you're asking about, but you should also say what it does to get a better response---there may be people here who know the answer, but don't know what StyleCop does...

Comment: Rather than saying "Similar to StyleCop" Please enumerate the features you feel are necessary for you to consider it "similar".  In other words, list what you want to use the tool for, don't just list the tool and say, "Find me something that kinda looks like this!"

Comment: possible duplicate of [A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards). This looks to be what you are after, although I don't know the full capability of the StyleCop tool.