# Can I enforce code style policy in eclipse IDE for c++ code?

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, rules

I want that whatever code style i defined in eclipse editor ..should be followed by coders, so can i enforce it as program will not even build without satisfying all the rules???

Answer (score 0):

It think that's not possible out of the box with Eclipse. 
There are two problems to solve:

#### Check the source code for satifying the rules.

There is no support for this in CDT, but there seem to be other tools (see discussion [A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)).

#### Integrate the check into the build process.

To catch all possible build chains (Internal CDT Build, Makefiles,...), you need to hook into the build process with your own builder which is executed before the CDT build. This requires a plugin to be written.
If your build is using makefiles, it should be rather easy to integrate such a tool into the build process.