# Is there a style checker for c++?

Tags: c++, coding-style, checkstyle

I have worked with java for a while now, and I found [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to be very useful. I am starting to work with c++ and I was wondering if there is a style checker with similar functionality. I am mainly looking for the ability to write customized checks.

Comment: What would be an example of a style violation? "Style" to my mind is entirely code formatting, but your comments below indicate that's not what you mean...

Comment: It is not that I don't want formatting as a part of it. I just want to know whether the formatting is correct. Also, I have used it for variable naming conventions

Comment: I think the eclipse CDT plugin will do some of what you want

Comment: A mandatory link: [SO: A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [Vera++](http://www.inspirel.com/vera/) ?

*Vera++ is a programmable tool for verification, analysis and transformation of C++ source code. 
Vera++ is mainly an engine that parses C++ source files and presents the result of this parsing to scripts in the form of various collections - the scripts are actually performing the requested tasks.*

Click [here](http://www.inspirel.com/vera/ce/demo.html) to see a more complete demo of what it can do.

```
crc.hpp:157: keyword 'explicit' not followed by a single space
crc.hpp:588: closing curly bracket not in the same line or column
dynamic_property_map.hpp:82: keyword 'if' not followed by a single space
functional.hpp:106: line is longer than 100 characters
multi_index_container.hpp:472: comma should be followed by whitespace
version.hpp:37: too many consecutive empty lines
weak_ptr.hpp:108: keyword 'catch' not followed by a single space
...
```

Comment: That looks promising, I will have to play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good feedback about [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) which allows to apply a uniform style on code without too much hassle.

It's free and there are plenty of "classic" styles already defined. It might not work with C++0x new constructs though.

I am also expecting a Clang library, though I haven't found any to date. Normally, given Clang's structure it should be relatively easy, but then it's always easier to say than to code and I guess nobody took the time yet.

Comment: AStyle is more of a beautifier and you cannot use it to actually check style violations as you can use checkstyle for Java.

Comment: I am actually looking for a style checker rather than a formatter. I would like to be able to create checks for my teams style conventions, and then run the checker to see if everyone following the conventions.

Comment: @megamug: but what's the point of having a "checker" report if something has been done right or not, when you could simply have a formatter pass in your makefiles to automatically make it right without humane intervention ?

Comment: Typically there is a process involved in changing existing code, meaning someone has to make sure that it still works the way that it did before. There is no process necessary for analyzing code.

Comment: @megamug: Ah... didn't worry much about testing to be fair, we have continuous integration where I work so any change that would break tests would be rejected anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[KWStyle](https://kitware.github.io/KWStyle/) seems to be a lightweight fit