# checkstyle equivalent for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)

hi,

is there tool equivalent to [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) for (visual) C++ ?

I wasn't able to find anything on the internet..

thanks...

**EDIT**
Duplicate of : [A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)

Comment: What does checkstyle do? Can you give us a description of the functionality that you are looking for? Not everyone familiar with one environment is familiar with *all* possible environments.

Comment: @Cody Gray: added a link to the sf project

Comment: @Benoit: Yeah, I have Google. The "Overview" on that page doesn't tell me a whole lot about what *exactly* this tool adds to the asker's workflow, and thus doesn't allow me to make very good recommendations.

Comment: thanks Georg, wasn't able to find the question.

Answer (score 2):

[uncrustify - Source Code Beautifier for C, C++](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this one on sourceforge: [GreatCode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcgreatcode/). I really like the configuration options that it provides for C/C++.