# Something similar to checkstyle for C++ to be working on Linux

Tags: java, c++

I am looking for some tool to help with C++ like `checkstyle`, which is for JAVA. It should be available for LINUX.

Are you guys aware of any?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)

Answer (score 6):

[Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) is the best free tool you are going to get.  If you're willing to spend money, there are a lot of very nice other tools out there.  If you want to hack up your own solution, you can do what I did for my job and hack up [cpplint](http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/source/browse/trunk/cpplint/cpplint.py) with any additional rules you want to add.

Comment: @aaa: cpplint does style as well (which was why I threw that one in too)

Comment: Cppcheck does not check style. From the link above: "Cppcheck focus on bugs instead of stylistic issues. Therefore a tool that focus on stylistic issues could be a good addition."

Answer (score 1):

[Vera](http://www.inspirel.com/vera/)

[Astyle (Artistic Style)](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)

[Universal Indent GUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/)

[Bcpp (C++ Beautifier)](http://invisible-island.net/bcpp/bcpp.html)

[Polystyle](http://www.polystyle.com/)

[Also see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005549/source-code-beautifier-for-c-vc)

Comment: Those are all links to code formatters (and one dead link) which are different from static analysis tools because with the latter only a check is performed and the dev is forced to correct the issues him_herself which has pro and con.

Comment: @KalleRichter that is true, but i know at least astyle has a dry run option. so can still be used as an analysis tool.

Comment: @ItayBianco: To my knowledge, the Astyle --dry-run option does not give any output or analysis, it just tests whether the tool itself can be run. If someone knows how to get analysis output out of that, I'd love to hear about it.