# Seeking C++ metrics tool for Linux

Tags: c++, code-metrics

I'm looking for a C++ code quality metrics tool that can run on Linux.  Having Eclipse integration would be a bonus but is not required.

I found a decent tool called [Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html), but that only works on Windows, and the source code is not available to rebuild on Linux.

I also saw [cccc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccc/) out there, but based on [the bug list](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=7763&atid=107763), it doesn't seem to be maintained any more.

Comment: Wine can run many Windows binaries unchanged on Linux, might be worth a try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what kinds of metrics you need, you might consider [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) that calculates lines of code metrics, or, for instance, [CCFinder](http://www.ccfinder.net/ccfinderxos.html) that calculates different metrics related to code duplication. CCFinder GUI version does not seem to work but the command line version seems to work just fine.

Moreover, many commercial tools, e.g., [CMT++ by Testwell](http://www.testwell.fi/eval.html) often can provide evaluation licenses.

Answer (score 2):

Some month ago, a colleage of mine had shown me the results of **cppdepends** analysis on a software we were working on, and I remember it gave me a good impression. You may [check their linux version](http://www.cppdepend.com/).

There is also [pmccabe](http://www.parisc-linux.org/~bame/pmccabe/overview.html) which has an available Debian/Ubuntu package. It computes the McCabe complexity for each function.

Comment: pmccabe works well and is shipped w/ Ubuntu (pkg pmccabe). Great!

Comment: I have added the Ubuntu package reference in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Metrix++ works on linux and has got some code quality metrics. http://metrixplusplus.sourceforge.net/