# Variable naming conventions verifier for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, naming-conventions, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)

Currently for my project, I'm using AStyle for indentation, and other issues,
But I'm looking for a tool, preferably a command line tool for Linux which check variable naming conventions (such as Hungarian notation).
does anyone knows if such a tool exists ?

Comment: Is opening a file or two and looking at the variable names too much trouble?

Comment: @Jordanm, if you have, for example, a file or two with 60k lines of code, it may be too much trouble, yea.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall You wouldn't have to read all 60k lines of code to see what variable naming patterns are being used. I guess I don't see a use case other than contributing development and wanting to keep consistent naming conventions (in which case, you are already looking at the code anyways).

Comment: @jordanm, Idk about the OP, but general speaking I clearly see a use-case "10 people contributed to the project, I want to know if they named the variables in a right way without looking though all the codez"...

Comment: @jordanm So you're saying that in a large project with dozens of programmers working on it, you should hire somebody that looks through every committed file to see whether all naming conventions were followed everywhere because that's more sensible than giving the job to someone who is much better at it anyhow (a machine?)?

Comment: I have not verified if any of these specifically support Hungarian notation checking, but there are plenty of links at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards (possible duplicate?)

Comment: Do you want it to just warn about Hungarian notation, or should it be removed automatically?  :-)

Comment: Yes, such a tool exists. It is called a 'human reviewer'. And it is surprising how many more problems it can bring to light.