# Is there any open source syntactic rule checker for C language?

Tags: c, coding-style, static-analysis

I discovered Frama-c but it mainly focused on semantic rather than syntactic rule checker. 
So is there any open source syntax checker which can do syntax checking and also customizable as per my rules ?

Comment: Are you looking for some [coding standards checker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)?

Comment: Yes anol. Actually we have our own custom rule which I want to add and check the c source code according to it and provide warning accordingly.

Comment: From the comments in the question I linked to previously, I'm afraid the wording in your question is less likely to attract good answers and might end up being considered as off-topic. Maybe you could follow the advice on the "closed as off-topic" box in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards) and try to reformulate a question with a more precise description of the problem. Also, I'd suggest adding tags [c] and [coding-style] instead of [frama-c], since the question is not specific to Frama-C at all.

Comment: Perhaps you might customize your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), but I am not sure to understand what you call a *syntactic rule checker* (stricto sensu, every compiler is checking the syntax of the source code it is compiling)