# Writing Custom rules for cppcheck

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I am using cppcheck for static analysis. To accelerate review process I want to set up cppcheck to look for some custom rules,
for example to check if geter functions defined as a const.

If anyone has experience in writing custom rules for cppcheck please can you provide some example to write custom rules?.

P.S I have done some research to find a tool which will allow me to write custom rules and make review process faster.
I have find these links about this topic

[What open source C++ static analysis tools are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/what-open-source-c-static-analysis-tools-are-available)

[C++ static code analysis tool on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97454/c-static-code-analysis-tool-on-windows)

[A free tool to check C/C++ source code against a set of coding standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards)

Comment: Hi, TM_.  Requests for offline resources and requests for tool suggestions are off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi @DrewDormann actually my question about writing custom rules for cppcheck. If even just mentioning also off-topic I can remove this part from my question.

Comment: I bet that would help.  I re-read each sentence that you typed and asked myself *"Is this a question?"*  I couldn't find a question anywhere.

Comment: @DrewDormann thanks for willing help. my question about writing custom rules for cppcheck . Edited my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

You can perhaps use the --rule and --rule-file options to add such rules. Maybe you can use a regular expression such as:

```
\sget[A-Za-z]+\(\)\s+{\s+return
```

It depends on your code base.

If you can write a regular expression then this is the most direct and simple way to create a custom rule.

For more information, read the "Writing rules" articles here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcheck/files/Articles/

But maybe you want to write more sophisticated rules that search for such getter methods by using the Cppcheck SymbolDatabase, tokenlist and syntax tree. You can't use --rule and --rule-file then. You have these choices then:

- Use --dump and write your own custom scripts that read the output data (xml).
- Write C++ code and compile it into Cppcheck. This is relatively straightforward imho but requires that you compile Cppcheck yourself.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Marjamäki Thanks for response. So as written in document you provided  rule is XML file, is there a way to use this custom created rule file with  cppcheck GUI ? Where can I set up new rule in GUI?

Comment: Currently you can't use rules in the GUI. I think it would be relatively easy to improve the GUI, but nobody has wanted to do it.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try to use with windows cmd terminal.